# Is there a way within expressjs.mongoosejs to set by default which fields are returned in your response?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

Is there a way to restrict which fields are sent in the response at a model level.  Assume I have the following schema:

```
var mySchema = new.mongoose.Schema({
    public_field1: String,
    public_field2: String,
    private_field1: String,
    private_field1: String,
})
```

Let's say I want to get all those fields back when I do my query because the private fields are used for some processing, but I only want to send the public fields to the final response.  What is the best way to handle that without having to specify it every single route function?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`select`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-select) property on the field definitions in your schema to determine if the field is included by default or not.  For example, to exclude the private fields by default:

```
var mySchema = new.mongoose.Schema({
    public_field1: String,
    public_field2: String,
    private_field1: {type: String, select: false},
    private_field2: {type: String, select: false}
})
```

Then when you do want those fields you can include them in your results via:

```
MyModel.find().select('+private_field1 +private_field2').exec(callback);
```

Comment: But as I mentioned, I want the private fields returned from my query.  I just dont want to send them in my response.  I obviously have to manipulate the result before sending it.  I am wondering if there is a global way to filter out fields before sending them as the response.